# Finding the coordinate ring for an affine set

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I know that $U =: \mathbb{P}^1 \setminus p$  which p is a point in projective space is affine. I am trying to find the coordinate ring in a specific case, in which the point is [1:-1] corresponding to the ideal  I generated by x+y=0. Is the coordinate ring $\frac {k[x,y,z]}{z(x+y)-1} $? I remember in the affine case, we did the same to going one dimension higher. Thanks!